# FFMPEG auto installer with latest version

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

I found [this](http://ffmpeginstaller.com) software which compiles FFMPEG with the older version.
Is there something like it with the latest version of FFMPEG.
Or how how can i update the FFMPEG after this auto install.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @bfhd CentOS 6.6 64

Answer (score 2):

According to an entry on the FFmpeg Auto Installer's ["support forum"](http://forum.syslint.com/topic/186/upgrading/), re-running the script should pull down the latest source and upgrade your installation for you.

Since said forum is pretty janky (tread carefully, traveler), I pulled the installer down and took a precursory look at its innards. It does appear that the FFmpeg-specific script is set up to pull the latest git code (`git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`), and will overwrite any previously compiled/installed version with a fresh version, so it appears the claim is correct.

NOTE/GENERAL WARNING: This Auto Installer is pretty much nothing more than a large collection of bash scripts which will only run under root credentials. While it appears that many of the scripts appear to be set up to download and install software from legit sources (official git repos and calls to either yum or apt-get for items from distro repos), I haven't been through all of it, and therefore won't guarantee there isn't something sinister hiding in its weeds. Users who are security conscious would be better off downloading from trusted, official sources and compiling manually.